# jquery popup registration form

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code for popping up a registration form.

http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/

I created a registration form inside the popup box and when i submit it i am redirected to a  new page. I am no longer inside the popup. Please let me know how to avoid going out of the popup box.

I am using php for validation. My file name is register.php. I included this file in popupbox. The code inside register.php has this format.

```
<?php

// code for validating fields submited in form

?>

<html>
<form action="register.php">
/// fields
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: The code inside register.php has following format

<?php

/// code for validating fields submitted in form
?>

<html>
<form action="register.php">
</form>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

You need to post the form using ajax and then update the html in the popup using data in the result.

Have a look at [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) e.g.

```
// send form testForm using ajax and update popup content
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize(), function(data){
    $("#myPopupContentId").html(data);
});
```

There are also a couple of plugins you can use that will simplify things, take a look at [this example](http://max.jsrhost.com/ajaxify/example.php?action=reg) for a demo.